# NodeJS wait for an axios+nedb function async/await to run next query

Tags: node.js, async-await, axios, nedb

I want to use Axios + nedb in a NodeJS Script to gather data from an API into a local file. This is what I done so far:

```
var axios = require('axios');
var Datastore = require('nedb');
const fs = require('fs');

db = new Datastore({ filename: './../smb_share/art.db', autoload: true });

function getArt(limit, offset) {
    var config = {
      method: 'get',
      url: 'http://IPADD/api/data/2:1/?limit=' + limit + '&offset=' + offset',
      headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/simple+json', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
        'Authorization': 'Basic XYZ'
      }
    };

    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
          response.data.erpDataObjects.forEach(element => {
              var doc = { number:element.head.number,
                          desc:element.head.desc
              };
              db.insert(doc, function (err, newDoc) {
                if(err =! null){
                  console.log(err);
                }   
            });
          });  
      })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });  
}

getArt(1000,0)
getArt(1000,1000)
```

This works fine, as long I am not gathering more data from the API. I need to call my function "getArt(limit, offset)"  round about 400 times, because I get about 400000 docs from the API. I tried to do this with intervalTimers, so start every 5min the function and ++offset with 1000 each time the interval event is fired... Yes, I know that's weird, but it was the only way which worked for me at the moment. But when the API server is on heavy load, it takes too long for one query and I exceed the limit of call which end up in a mess.

My Question: how do I keep things clear and fire the functions when the function before is ready? I tried a lot of async/await stuff, but all ended up in errors or all was fired at the same time. What I basically need is something like ...

```
getArt(10000,0)
.then
getArt(10000,10000)
.then
getArt(10000,20000)
.then
...
```

But with the nested function of axios I don't know how to handle this with a promise. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried making `getArt` an `async function` and simply `awaiting` it?

```
async function getArt(limit, offset){...}

async function Name(){
  await getArt(10000, 1000); // wait to complete before moving on
  await getArt(10000, 2000); // only execute when above is done
}

Name();
```

By not assigning the result of `await`, you simply tell your program to **wait** for this function to complete prior to moving on to next one.

**Side Note:**

Why not make a for loop which increments the offset and calls the `getArt` function?

```
async function Name(){
  var limit = 10000;
  for(let offset = 0; offset < limit; offset += limit/10){
    await getArt(limit, offset);
  }
}

Name();
```

I haven't tested this, but see no reason why it should not work.

Additionally, (to follow good practice guidelines) you should wrap your `await` statements in a `try-catch` block to deal with errors like so:

```
try{
  await getArt(limit, offset);
}
catch(err){
  console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @lbragile, I think i tried the simple async await function, but it ran through all function calls without waiting for the previous one. Also thanks for the Side Note, what I wanted to do when the wait works. I will give it a try again tomorrow in production to see if I made a mistake in my experimental code.

Comment: @Matthias, something isn't adding up here, if you did async/await like I mentioned then the function should "wait" for a response prior to moving on to the next line. Do you mind sharing your implementation? Are you sure you did **async** function getArt(limit, offest){...}?

Comment: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: @Matthias As I mentioned twice, you need to use `async function getArt(limit, offset){}` in order to use `await getArt(limit, offset)`.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I chekced it twice and my function is: async function getArt(limit, offset) {...} thats one thing what confuses me.

Comment: @Matthias, I see my apologies, misunderstood your comment. You actually need to make the call in an async function:

`async function getArt(limit, offset){}
async function Name(){
 await getArt(limit, offset);}}` Then call `Name()`. That should fix it!

Comment: @Matthias, edited my original answer to reflect this. Let me know if there are still issues

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work. Just for my understanding.. when I put a "console.log('api called') on top of the function "async function getArt(limit, offset){}, shouldn't than appear step by step "api called"? now it's just running through and "api called" pops up 40 times immediatly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223800/discussion-between-lbragile-and-matthias).